# AS3 Air Native Extension com.distriq.Core conflits with other ANEs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air-native-extension, ane, distriqt

I'm facing the issue with the com.distriq.Core ANE, it's conflicting with my other ANEs (I know it when I remove it from app packaging, but after include this ANE, Flash Builder was failed to build).

Here is the error message:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

dx tool failed:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/adobe/air/ActivityResultCallback;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:737)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:678)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:607)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:637)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:511)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:281)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
1 error; aborting
```

So I'm asking for an advise, what should I do now?

Much appreciated !

Comment: does distriqt provides source codes of this ANE?

Comment: no, @payamsbr. They only provide the ANEs.

Comment: you have to find another problematic ANE (which cant be used beside `com.distriqt.core`) then if that is open source, you may fix issue, other wise no way

Comment: @payamsbr damn.. I've researched on google, someone talked about unzip the ANE, remove the duplicated JAR file and repackage them.. sounds simple.. but there is no detailed instruction, so I don't really know where to start :(

Comment: in past i did some thing like this too, do you have **Winrar** or **7-zip**?

Comment: @payamsbr of course I do, I unziped the ANE already, deleted the JAR file, then.. what next? :)

Comment: don't need for unzipping, only open up Winrar, then drag ane to its window, modify what you want, then ane will be updated automatically

Comment: Note, may be it will be important to reordering Modified Ane to be added to AIR(project) after other ANE's that contains removed JAR

Comment: I've just tried that, but still doesn't work. When I compile, FB through this error "com.distriqt.Core.ane is not a valid native extension file."

Comment: maybe it should be packed via AIR SDK, i'm not sure, read [**this article**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt5.html) and test your chance with generating a valid ANE with lack of problematic JAR.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @payamsbr, I will give it a shot :)

Comment: Good-luck :) please post the right answer when you got that, its a good question and would be helpful for many persons.

Comment: Unluckily still no success @payamsbr, I'm reaching the support team of Distriqt, will update the answer later

Answer (score 3):

The support team from Distriqt already provided me an new ANE called "com.distriq.Core.noair.com" with the conflicted JAR file is removed.

https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-Core/tree/master/lib

In case someone want to know which ANE it was conflicting with, it's "overideAir.ane" from MyFlashLab team.

Big thumbs up for the amazing support from Distriqt!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The conflict will be with an ANE from another provider, if you contact our support we will work with you to remove the classes that are conflicting with your other ANEs.

Comment: Well, I already submit an issue on Github Private of Distriqt, waiting for their response :)

Comment: If you haven't gotten a response already shoot me the link and I'll look into it.

Comment: I believe your team is looking on it, anyway here is the link: https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-GoogleIdentity/issues/13 Thanks for your support !